# Count() using Where clause and Left Join

Tags: mysql, join, count, where-clause

I have a query similar to the following:

> SELECT 
>   users.id FROM users LEFT JOIN sales ON installations.customer = users.id

What I would like to say is something like "WHERE count(sales.id) > 4" - meaning that if the user has more than 4 sales assoc with them. I am not sure if I am going about this the wrong way or not though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select
    users.id

from users

join sales on /* your join condition here */

group by users.id

having count(sales.id) > 4
```

This will group all of the sales by user, then return only those sales that have more than four records in the `sales` table.

I didn't duplicate your join condition from above because it didn't seem to make much sense, as it's referencing tables that aren't in your query anywhere.

Comment: Oh yeah I meant to join the sales in both, this works though thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something similar to this

```
select users.id, count(sales.id)
from users
LEFT JOIN sales ON installations.customer = users.id
group by users.id
having count(Sales.id) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "group by" and "having" clause.

Try

```
SELECT users.id FROM users LEFT JOIN sales ON installations.customer = users.id GROUP BY users.id HAVING count(sale.id) > 4
```

See here for more [GROUPBY on W2C](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)